# Slicing on shared pointer reassignment

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Is it always safe to reassign a `std::shared_ptr<A>` to point to values of type `B`, where `B` is a subclass of `A`? Specifically, in the following code:

```
class A {};

class B : public A {
    int arr[1000];
};


int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<A> pa = std::make_shared<A>();
    *pa = B();
}
```

`B` has a much larger size than `A`, so if the shared pointer were to have only allocated enough memory for objects of type `A`, we would be overflowing. Is this properly handled by the library? I have been experiencing issues in a larger project with similar code, and they went away when I added a layer of indirection (`shared_ptr<shared_ptr<A>>`)

Comment: That code does not reassign the pointer.

Comment: You need to handle slicing by yourself.

Comment: Whats the proper terminology for reassigning what the pointer points to?

Comment: a pointer points to a value.

Comment: Yes I know that. The question is what happens if you change which value the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: You're changing the value inside the object the pointer points to.  But it's still the same object, no change to the pointer.

Comment: I know. But is there a guarantee that I can change the value, given it will require more memory than the previous value?

Comment: You're not changing the type of the value, so the amount of memory doesn't change either.  If you need to change the type, the double indirection you already mentioned is your solution.

Comment: Am I not changing it from `A` to `B`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are slicing your `B` object down to an `A` in that assignment.  The assignment in your example is no different than if `shared_ptr` wasn't involved at all:

```
int main() {
    A a;
    a = B();
}
```

The only difference is that you're assigning to the object pointed to by `pa` rather than a local object.

If you actually want to make your `shared_ptr` point to a new `B` object, you need to allocate one and assign to the pointer rather than the object pointed to:

```
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<A> pa = std::make_shared<A>();
    pa = std::make_shared<B>();
}
```

Or if you don't need the `A` object in the first place:

```
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<A> pa = std::make_shared<B>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Issue is that I need the reassignment to be observable by all preexisting pointers, so using the `shared ptr`'s assignment operator won't work. Looks like double indirection it is. It would be nice if there were a way to request enough storage for the largest possible subclass. Or maybe force reallocation of memory to the new object's size.